# Selenium WebDriver "Cannot instantiate class " error is coming

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, testng, page-objects, page-factory

Below is my Base Class:

```
package com.mercury.qa.base;


import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


import com.mercury.qa.util.TestUtil;

public class BaseTest {

public static WebDriver driver;
public static Properties prop;

public BaseTest(){

    try {
        prop = new Properties();
        //FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Pdeshmukh1\\workspace\\MercuryToursPreet\\src\\main\\java\\com\\mercury\\qa\\config\\config.properties");
        FileInputStream ip = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("C:\\Users\\Pdeshmukh1\\workspace\\MercuryToursPreet\\src\\main\\java\\com\\mercury\\qa\\config\\config.properties"));

        prop.load(ip);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void initialization(){
    String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");

    if(browserName.equals("chrome")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Pdeshmukh1\\Music\\chromedriver.exe");    
        driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
    }
    else if(browserName.equals("FF")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Pdeshmukh1\\Music\\geckodriver.exe");  
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
    }
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TestUtil.Page_Wait_Timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(TestUtil.Implicit_wait, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));

}
}
```

Below is my Page class:

```
package com.mercury.qa.pages;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import com.mercury.qa.base.BaseTest;

public class LoginPage extends BaseTest {

//PageFactory : Object Repository 

     @FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='SIGN-ON']")
     WebElement SignOnLink;

     @FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='REGISTER']")
     WebElement RegisterLink;

     @FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='SUPPORT']")
     WebElement SupportLink;

     @FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='CONTACT']")
     WebElement ContactLink;

     @FindBy(xpath = "//body/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/p[1]/img[1]")
     WebElement MercuryLogo;

    //Initializing the Page Objects:
     public LoginPage(){

         PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

     }

     //Actions:
     public String ValidateLoginPageTitle(){
         return driver.getTitle();
     }

     public boolean ValidateSignOnLink(){
         return SignOnLink.isDisplayed();            
     }


     public boolean ValidateRegisterLink(){         
         return RegisterLink.isDisplayed();              
     }


     public boolean ValidateSupportLink(){          
         return SupportLink.isDisplayed();           
     }


     public boolean ValidateContactLink(){          
         return ContactLink.isDisplayed();           
     }

     public boolean ValidatepageLogo(){         
         return MercuryLogo.isDisplayed();           
     }

     public RegistrationPage OpenRegPage(){
         RegisterLink.click();           
         return new RegistrationPage();
     }


}
```

Below is my test Class

```
package com.mercury.qa.testcase;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.mercury.qa.base.BaseTest;
import com.mercury.qa.pages.LoginPage;
import com.mercury.qa.pages.RegistrationPage;

public class LoginPageTest extends BaseTest{

LoginPage loginPage;
RegistrationPage RegPage;

public LoginPageTest(){     
 super();
}

@BeforeMethod
public void setup(){
    initialization();       
    loginPage  = new LoginPage(); //initializing Loginpage constructor
}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void loginPageTitleTest(){
    String Title = loginPage.ValidateLoginPageTitle();
    Assert.assertEquals(Title, "Welcome: Mercury Tours");       
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void MercuryLogoTest(){
    boolean flag = loginPage.ValidatepageLogo();
    Assert.assertTrue(flag);
}

@Test(priority = 3)
public void LinksTest(){
    boolean flag1 = loginPage.ValidateSignOnLink();
    Assert.assertTrue(flag1);
    boolean flag2 = loginPage.ValidateRegisterLink();
    Assert.assertTrue(flag2);
    boolean flag3 = loginPage.ValidateContactLink();
    Assert.assertTrue(flag3);
    boolean flag4 = loginPage.ValidateSupportLink();
    Assert.assertTrue(flag4);

}

@Test(priority = 4)
public void OpenRegPage(){
    RegPage = loginPage.OpenRegPage();
}


@AfterMethod
public void TearDown(){
    driver.quit();
}

}
```

Below is the error i am getting:

> {
>
> org.testng.TestNGException:  Cannot instantiate class
>   com.mercury.qa.testcase.LoginPageTest     at
>   org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:38)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance1(ClassHelper.java:387)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.createInstance(ClassHelper.java:299)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:110)
>     at org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getInstances(ClassImpl.java:195)   at
>   org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.(TestNGClassFinder.java:120)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:160)     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:144)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG.java:273)
>     at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:561)
>     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:111)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1272)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1259)    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1113)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)   at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:115)     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:207)  at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:178) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.ObjectFactoryImpl.newInstance(ObjectFactoryImpl.java:29)
>     ... 21 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.mercury.qa.base.BaseTest.(BaseTest.java:26)     at
>   com.mercury.qa.testcase.LoginPageTest.(LoginPageTest.java:18)
>     ... 26 more }

Answer (score 1):

Judging by this:

```
Java.lang.NullPointerException at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source) 
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(Unknown Source) 
    at com.mercury.qa.base.BaseTest.(BaseTest.java:26) 
    at com.mercury.qa.testcase.LoginPageTest.(LoginPageTest.java:18) ... 26 more }
```

The properties file cannot be found - you should fix the path, or create a folder `resources` and use `Classloader` to load the file like this:

```
prop.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("properties_file"));
```